# How to delete UICollectionView Section Footer Programmatically

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, footer

I'm using UICollectionView with Section Footer which contains Activity indicator

I want to delete or hide the footer in some case

I used this way , but it doesn't work 100%

```
var footerView:FooterView!
```

...

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        switch kind {
        case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter:
            footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(
                ofKind: kind,
                withReuseIdentifier: "footer",
                for: indexPath) as? FooterView
            return footerView!
        default:
            assert(false, "Invalid element type")
        }
    }
```

And for hiding the footer

```
self.footerView.alpha = 0
```

Comment: Why not return `nil` from`viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` when you don't want a footer for the given indexPath?

Comment: i want to delete it when i receive empty results from the server , so it will be dynamic

Comment: So return `nil` from `fromviewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` when you don't want the footer. Of course you need to tell the collection view to reload the section.

Comment: 'nil' is incompatible with return type 'UICollectionReusableView'

Answer (score -1):

Try to implement the height method

```
var show = false

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                  layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
 referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return show ? CGSize(width:collectionView.frame.width,height:50) : CGSize.zero
}
```

Change the variable and reload the collection

Comment: Bad method because of full collection reload (in case of batch updates)